# Custom login form

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I am very new to WordPress. I am trying to display a login form in the header section of my website. However, when I look at all of the files in my directory it is very overwhelming and I am afraid to touch anything.

Does anyone know of any good tutorials on the topic or  perhaps shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The login form is a simple html form sending username and password to wp-login.php. This is the simplest way to create a custom login form:

```
<?php
$redirect_to = '';
?>
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-login.php' ); ?>" method="post">
<p>Username: <input id="user_login" type="text" size="20" value="" name="log"></p>
<p>Password: <input id="user_pass" type="password" size="20" value="" name="pwd"></p>
<p><input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" name="rememberme"></p>

<p><input id="wp-submit" type="submit" value="Login" name="wp-submit"></p>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $redirect_to ); ?>" name="redirect_to">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="testcookie">
</form>
```

Line by line:

- `$redirect_to`: If you want the user redirect to a special page, insert the url here. The url will be inserted in the hidden field at the end of the formular
- `<form ... action="...">`: The data has to be send to wp-login.php. This file is in the root of your WordPress installation. Create the right url with `site_url()` (please refer to the codex for more information about `site_url()`). The method has to be set to `post`
- A input field for the username with id `user_login`
- A input field for the password with id `user_pass`
- A input field for the 'RememberMe' checkbox (optional)
- A submit button
- The hidden field if the user should be redirected after login (optional)
- A hidden field for a testcookie (optional, but usefull)

Create a formular and style it with css. That's all.

Answer (score 9):

1. Create a template file within your child theme directory, let's say `login.php`. Put the login form inside this file:

   ```
   <form action="" method="post">
     <div>
       User name: <input name="log" type="text" />
     </div>
     <div>
       Password: <input name="pwd" type="password" />
     </div>
     <div>
       <input type="submit" value="Login" />
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_login_action" />
     </div>
   </form>
   ```

   Change whatever you wish, but you should leave the name attributes intact
2. Create a `functions.php` file within your child theme directory, or if you have one, edit it. You will fulfill the login requests in it:

   ```
   add_action('init', function(){

     // not the login request?
     if(!isset($_POST['action']) || $_POST['action'] !== 'my_login_action')
       return;

     // see the codex for wp_signon()
     $result = wp_signon();

     if(is_wp_error($result))
       wp_die('Login failed. Wrong password or user name?');

     // redirect back to the requested page if login was successful    
     header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
     exit;
   });
   ```
3. Create a copy of your `header.php` template, put it in your child theme folder and edit it. Add this code where you want the login form to appear:

   ```
   <?php

    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
      get_template_part('login');
    }

   ?>
   ```

Comment: I absolutely love this example. What would I have to write for the same thing but a register form instead of $result = wp_signon(); ?

Comment: [`wp_create_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can customize the original login form in your WP Theme.

There are a few things that you can do.
1) You can change the Wp logo :

```
<?php
//Custom logo
function my_custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        h1 a { background-image:url('.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/logo.png) !important; }
    </style>';
}

add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login_logo');

// Custom login

function my_login_logo_url() {
    return get_bloginfo( 'url' );
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'my_login_logo_url' );
function my_login_logo_url_title() {
    return '[url]';
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );

?>
```

2) You can remove the shake of WP login:

```
<?php

function my_login_head() {
    remove_action('login_head', 'wp_shake_js', 12);
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_login_head');

?>
```

3) Remove the login errors :

```
<?php

add_filter('login_errors',create_function('$a', "return null;"));

?>
```

Important: 
Do not use all of these parts of code to `functions.php`. First create three of them with the names that describe the `function` like *(ex `my_custom_login_logo.php`, `my_login_head.php` and `remove_login_errors.php`)* and then call the 3 functions to `functions.php` 
**e.x.** 
`require_once('includes/secure/my_custom_login_logo.php');`
`require_once('includes/secure/my_login_head.php');`
`require_once('includes/secure/remove_login_errors.php');`

includes and secure, are folders. I hope to help you. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

adding codes to wp-login.php. form codes below.

```
    <form id="loginform" action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-login.php' ); ?>" method="POST">

                            <h5><strong>ÜYE GİRİŞİ</strong>  <a href="uyeol.html"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> ÜYELİK OLUŞTUR.</a></h5>
                            <div class="newsletter-form">

                                <div class="newsletter-email">
                                    <input id="user_login" type="text" name="grs_tcno" value="" placeholder="Kullanıcı">
                                </div>

                                <div class="newsletter-zip">
                                    <input id="user_pass" type="password" name="grs_sifre" value="" placeholder="Parola">
                                </div>

                                <div class="newsletter-submit">
                                    <input id="wp-submit" type="submit" name="girisyap" value="login">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $redirect_to ); ?>" name="redirect_to">
                                      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="testcookie">
                                    <i class="icons icon-right-thin"></i>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Comment: There is never a good hint to edit the core files!